# Setting domain records correctly based on predefined ones

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I bought a new domain (let's call it **example.com**) from a domain provider (let's call it **provider.com**).

I would like to point the domain to my server. The thing is that the provider automatically created lots of domain records out of the box:

```
+------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|       NAME       | RECORD TYPE |                        VALUE                         |
+------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| ipv6.example.com | AAAA        | (IPv6 address)                                       |
| example.com      | MX          | 10 example.com                                       |
| example.com      | A           | (IPv6 address)                                       |
| example.com      | NS          | dns.provider.com dns2.provider.com dns3.provider.com |
| example.com      | SOA         | dns.provider.com admin.provider.com                  |
| example.com      | TXT         | "v=spf1 mx a ptr ~all"                               |
| mail.example.com | CNAME       | example.com                                          |
| ftp.example.com  | CNAME       | example.com                                          |
| www.example.com  | CNAME       | example.com                                          |
| *.example.com    | CNAME       | example.com                                          |
+------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I originally wanted to do, was to add a new `A` record and 2 `CNAME` records for *www* and subdomains. But with all the records the provider set, I'm not sure which records to touch now.

**Generally speaking:** which records do I need to change and which not?

**More specifically:** I assume that I still want to update the `A` record to the IPv4 of my server. But what with the `AAAA` / `MX` / `NS` / `SOA` records?
 And further: what with the `mail` and `ftp` subdomain entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `www.example.com` is a CNAME to `example.com`, do not change that record.

For your website, update `A` record with the relevant IP and add for the same label `example.com` an `AAAA` record only if your hosting company gave you an IPv6 address for your host and when everything is configured to work with it (hence the `ipv6` record may be a temporary entry to test things out before putting the `AAAA` directly under `www`.)

If you do not use it anywhere, remove `ipv6.example.com`. Also if you are not going to do mass subdomains hosting, I recommend removing `*.example.com` as wildcards in the DNS create more problems than anything else.
Of course, create explicit records for your subdomains, and either make them `CNAME` of `example.com` like `www` (if the subdomains are hosted on the same box as `www` of course) or add explicit `A`/`AAAA` records for them (if they are hosted elsewhere or on same box as `www`).

Remove `mail.example.com` and `ftp.example.com` if you do not use them: it is silly nowadays to use the `FTP` protocol anymore and `mail.example.com` could be useful if you have email for this domain, but if not remove it and also the `MX` (it is only needed if you are receiving emails to `*@example.com`). The `TXT` record you have if also only useful if you are sending emails **from** `something@example.com`, so if not remove it.

You could of course add back things later on if you decide to do emails or something.

Do not touch the `NS` records unless you are changing your DNS hosting provider (and know what you are doing)

Do not touch the `SOA` record for the same reason (it is even silly that your provider gives you access to that)

There are other combinations possible, the previous is just one way.